# Deleting rows in vba doesn't work

Tags: vba, excel

I've got part of my code:

```
o = Workbooks(repfile).Worksheets(1).Range("b:b").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
For k = o To 2 Step -1
    If Left(Cells(k, 7), 1) <> "1" Or IsEmpty(Cells(k, 7)) = True Then
    cells(k,7).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next
```

But it just doesn't work. If I switch

```
cells(k,7).EntireRow.Delete
```

With e.g.

```
cells(k,7).Interior.ColorIndex=1
```

Then it works perfectly. But it just doesn't want to delete rows.

Comment: Yes, I made I mistake in a post, as I was trying this method both with "For Each cell in rng" and with Cells

Comment: If it's not deleting rows it means the conditions are not being met.

Comment: Try `cells(1,7).EntireRow.Delete` if it deletes the row, then something with the `k` parameter is wrong.

Comment: @JohnyL - OP has edited the code, I'll delete my comment.

Comment: That's the strangest thing I saw- when I changed to    cells(1,7)EntireRow.Delete    then it worked. I changed to k again, and it started working correctly

Comment: Check it's doing it on the right sheet. You haven't explicitly declare where your cell is so this code will work on whatever the active sheet is. Try using `Sheets("SheetName").Cells(k,7).EntireRow.Delete` instead

Comment: try what Tom ^^ has said.  Basically, Cells is not specific enough, provide the workbook and worksheet you are referring to or VBA will have issues.  Thisworbook.Worksheets("yourworksheetname").Cells since you are using cells in multiple places instead use a With statement before this code.  Better yet name your worksheet and refer to it directly to avoid any issue of the worksheet name change. I will post similar code - WWC